# HTML:Highlight selected link or label

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In my Html Page I need to keep the link  selected when i click on it:
The HTML Code:

```
    <table class="main-dev">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelA
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelB
            </a>
        </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelC
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelD
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The Other option is to change the link with simple label, and need to keep the label selected when click on it:
The Html code will be:

```
    <table class="main-dev">
    <tr>
        <td>
                labelA
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                labelB
        </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                labelC
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                labelD
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: _I need to keep the link selected when i click on it..._ until when? Please clarify your question.

Comment: i need the link selected until i click on another link, then the other link will be selected

Comment: check answer below. let me know if it is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily with JQ . see snippet below

if you want to remove `selected` class when click again on the same link, change `addClass` to `toggleClass`

```js
var link = $(".titleForm")
    
$(link).on("click",function() {
     var otherLinks = $(this).parents("tr").siblings().find(".selected")

   $(this).addClass("selected")
   $(otherLinks).removeClass("selected")

    
})
```

```css
.selected {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="main-dev">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelA
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelB
            </a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelC
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class='titleForm' style="cursor:pointer">
                labelD
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```